# SVN client can not access repository on CloudForge on one computer. Works fine on another. Error msg PROPFIND 405 Methods not allowed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was working on a project that I have checked in to SVN. I am using CloudForge to host my SVN data. All was working well from all three computers that I am using (Windows 8 laptop, Windows 7 VMware session, Mac). I recently upgraded my Windows 7 computer to TortoiseSVN 1.8.xxxx from 1.7.xxxx. At approximately the same time the Windows 7 machine would not let me commit through TortoiseSVN anymore. I would get this error.

> svn: E175002: PROPFIND request on '/henksprojects' failed: 405 Method Not Allowed

When I tried to repository browse I would get the same error. I checked the other two computers and they are still working fine. I uninstalled TortoiseSVN and SVN completely, rebooted and reinstalled but still get the error. When I try this from the command line:

```
svn ls https://hvanbrug@mpssoftware.svn.cloudforge.com/henksprojects
```

I also get that error. When I try to force my password into the URL, I get a different error.

```
svn: E020014: Unable to connect to a repository at URL  https://hvanbrug:xxxxx@mpssoftware.svn.cloudforge.com/henksprojects'

svn: E020014: Error running context: Internal error
```

It seems like this computer (VM) can no longer access my SVN data at all any more.

All the stuff I have found so far indicates that this is likely a problem either with how the server is set up or that I have a duplicate directory already in the repository, but that doesn't match what I am seeing or trying to do. I can not list the contents of the repository. I have completely removed my working copy from this computer. I have no access to the server, and in any event, the other two computers are still working fine.

I hope someone out there knows what might be going on.

Interestingly, I just reinstalled back down to 1.7.11.xxx, and it all works again. Still no luck on 1.8.

Both versions I installed were 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted CloudForge and they responded with the following:

"We suggest you to use TortoiseSVN 1.7.x clients only as we are using SVN version 1.7.9 on our servers. If you are able to access the repository from other machines that should be specific to that machine. Hope the information was helpful. Please let us know if you have any further queries."

I assumed that a 1.8 client would be compatible with a 1.7 server, but it appears that this is not always the case, so at least for this machine I will be going back to a 1.7 client.

Comment: Any 1.x client can work with any 1.x server.  SVN 1.8 has replaced the library it uses for HTTP communication and it would be fair to describe the release so far as "buggy". Most have been for somewhat edge cases like certain proxy servers or authentication schemes.  I have personally not had any problems with 1.8

Comment: Interesting. So it would seem that windows 7 in a VMWare virtual machine might be one of those edge cases. I was really hoping that CloudForge could have given me a more detailed answer than just "don't do it". Thanks.

Comment: I lead the CloudForge engineering team, sorry that you did not get a more accurate answer the first time. I did educate the support rep after I saw the response.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I am glad you were able to wipe away some of my cobwebs. :)

Comment: I was having a similar issue in Cygwin Subversion v1.8 (not with CloudForge).  Downgrading to Subversion v1.7 in Cygwin solved the issue.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I understand your desire to correct the grammar of CloudForge's response. I put it in there as it was because that was a direct quote of their response. I went on the assumption that the most accurate facsimile of their response would be the most useful and the least likely for accidental misinterpretation.

Comment: Once again, I rejected another edit just now. The editor was trying to remove the quotes. As this is a direct quote from CloudForge the quotes must stay in place.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar error when I created a new project. After searching for a while and trying it out from multiple systems with different versions of an SVN client, I finally logged a ticket at https://help.cloudforge.com/home.

I got the below response after an hour of ticket submission:

> *We have run a resync of svn service, request you to wait for sometime and try the access as the repositories are just created and it may require some time to sync*

I tried it again after a few more hours, and the issue was resolved on its own. Please try contacting help if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: Ok. I just reinstalled 1.8.1 to prove it is still a problem, and then I submitted the question to cloudforge. Now we wait. :)

Comment: Got a response from CloudForge. They told me to not use a 1.8 client as they are using a 1.7.9 server.